# How to use go.Scatter() from plotly to create animated scatter plot

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

I have this code which uses NFL tracking data (sample provided below) which is used to create an animated figure (I've attached an image of this). However, I was wondering how my px.scatter() part could be rewritten into using go.Scatter() (a graph object) instead?

```
fig = px.scatter(data,  x = "x", y = "y", hover_name="displayName",
          color="team", animation_frame = "frameId", animation_group = "displayName",
          range_y = [-5, 60], range_x = [-5, 125], 
          color_discrete_map = dict((["home", home], ["away", away], ["football", football])))
```

[Screenshot of the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDiQB.png)

Sample data:

| x | y | team | frameId | displayName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 61.21 | 46.77 | home | 1 | Mahomes |
| 60 | 32 | away | 1 | Beckham |

Comment: What you have realized is that you want to add a scatter plot to the animation? Or do you want to rewrite the express animation into a graph object?

Comment: I would like to rewrite the express animation into a graph object if possible

Comment: If that is the case, please refer to the [official example](https://plotly.com/python/animations/#using-a-slider-and-buttons) of animation with a graph object. Before that, it would be helpful to analyze the contents of the animation in express to understand it better. `fig.data`, `fig.layout,` `fig.frame`